# generating prime numbers in pl/sql

Tags: plsql

Please tell me the problem in the code. I have written this code and its not working. Tell me the mistakes or if there is any other and easy method to generate prime numbers till 1000.

```
declare 
    i number;
    prime number;
    j number;
begin 
    for i in 2 .. 1000 loop
            prime := 0;
            for j in 2 .. i/2 loop
            if mod(i,j)=0 then prime := 1
            end if;
        end loop;
    if prime = 0 then dbms_output.put_line(i||'&');
    end if;
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: What does "its not working" mean? Do you get an error? If yes, what is the *precise* error you are getting? Does the actual result differ from the expected result? If yes, what is the result you are expecting, why are you expecting that result, what is the actual result and how do they differ?  Does the observed behavior of the code differ from the intended behavior? If yes, what is the intended behavior and why, what is the behavior you are seeing, and how do they differ? What is the specification for the intended behavior? Please, provide sample testcases of the expected results.

Comment: Also, there are only 168 primes below 1000, are you sure it makes sense to compute them over and over rather than to just store them once?

Comment: I can see that there is a `;` missing after `prime := 1`. Is that the error? I'm getting the set of primes when I put that semi colon.

Comment: I was trying it on the hackerrank and not getting any output after putting that semicolon

Comment: Not sure about hackerrank, but is there any option to turn on `serveroutput`. Can you run the command `set serveroutput on`?

Answer (score 1):

You already have your answer (missing semicolon), but just for fun:

- The `i` variable declared at the top is not used.
- In theory `j` would be more efficient as a `pls_integer` (as `i` is implicitly). Possibly even a `simple_integer`, but then you'd need to restructure the loop to make `i` a `simple_integer` as well, and it's barely worth it for the tiny fraction of a second you might gain, if the compiler hasn't already optimised it.
- You might as well exit the inner loop at the first match, rather than checking every single number.
- `prime` would be more readable as a Boolean.
- On the subject of readability, it is standard practice to align `end loop` under its opening `loop` statement.
- I'm not seeing the point of appending `&` to every line of output.

This gives me:

```
declare
    j pls_integer;
    prime boolean;
begin
    for i in 2 .. 1000 loop
        prime := true;

        for j in 2 .. i/2 loop
            if mod(i,j) = 0 then
                prime := false;
                exit;
            end if;
        end loop;

        if prime then
            dbms_output.put_line(i);
        end if;

    end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed one semicolon and try to put set server output on then run it

```
set serveroutput on
declare 
    i number;
    prime number;
    j number;
begin 
    for i in 2 .. 1000 loop
            prime := 0;
            for j in 2 .. i/2 loop
            if mod(i,j)=0 then prime := 1;
            end if;
        end loop;
    if prime = 0 then dbms_output.put_line(i||'&');
    end if;
    end loop;
end;
 /
```